# React-select option not getting selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-select

I am using the [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) package. When i select a drop-down option, my onChange action works correctly and updates the state. But the option is not getting selected. Meaning, it doesn't show the value which is mapped to the state, instead just the default placeholder.

I think i'm missing something small, but i'm some what new to react and redux and i'm not sure what this could be. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Body.js

```
<Select id="input-field" value={this.props.create.selectedOption} onChange={this.props.addOption}
   options={[
      { value: 'navigate', label: 'Navigate to <URL>' },
      { value: 'enter', label: 'I enter <InputValue> to the <ElementKey>' },
      { value: 'click', label: 'Click on <ElementKey>' },
      ]}
/>


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        create: state.reducerCreate
    }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    feature: '',
    scenarios: [],
    activeIndex: '',
    selectedOption: ''
}
```

Comment: Is your redux store getting updated ? It's better if you control the `<Select>` component using `state` rather than `props`

Comment: yes the store is getting updated @Dane

Comment: Then maybe `this.props.create.selectedOption` is `undefined` ? Like I said, it's better if you use `this.state` to manage the `Select` component as only that will get re-rendered, instead of changing `props`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found out that just passing the selected options label/value is not enough we need pass the entire object;

```
{ value: 'navigate', label: 'Navigate to <URL>' }
```

Then we map our select tag's value attribute with the state's value.

Updated **Body.js**;

```
<Select id="input-field" componentClass="select" value={this.props.create.selectedOption.value} onChange={this.props.addOption}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        addOption: (option) => {
            console.log(option)
            dispatch(addOption(option))
        }
    };
};
```